# Branching when negative accumulator

Tags: loops, little-man-computer

I'm trying to create a loop that will print if a number given is odd or even (Par). How do I branch the loop when the accumulator value is -1?

```
START   INP // int(input(""))
        STA n // n =
LOOP    LDA n //
        BRZ END // while n !=0:
        SUB En // n - 1 
        STA n // n = 
        INP // int(input(""))
        ADD sum //
        STA sum //
        BRA LOOP //
END     LDA sum
        OUT
        BRP PO
PO      LDA sum
        BRZ EXIT
        LDA sum
        SUB TO
        STA sum
        BRA PO
ODDE    LDA O
        OTC
        LDA D
        OTC
        LDA D
        OTC
        LDA E
        OTC
O       DAT 79
D       DAT 68
E       DAT 69
        HLT
EXIT    BRP PAR
        HLT
PAR     LDA P
        OTC
        LDA A
        OTC
        LDA R
        OTC 
P       DAT 80
A       DAT 65
R       DAT 82
        HLT
TO      DAT 2
n       DAT 0
sum     DAT 0
En      DAT 1
Par     DAT -1
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I branch the loop when the accumulator value is -1?

The LMC defines mailboxes with values between 0 and 999. They cannot be negative. Even though you can subtract a bigger value from a smaller value, the accumulator's value is then undefined. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_man_computer#Instructions):

> `SUBTRACT` [...] the actions of the accumulator are not defined for subtract instructions that cause negative results - however, a negative flag will be set so that 7xx (BRZ) and 8xx (BRP) can be used properly.

So the only way to reliably detect a negative value is by using `BRP`: that branch instruction will jump to the provided target address *unless* a recent subtraction had set the negative flag.

### Code review

There are the following issues in your code:

- `Par     DAT -1`: as stated above, you cannot store -1 in an LMC mailbox. Mailboxes can only store values between 000 and 999.
- `Par` versus `PAR`: you have two labels that only differ in capitalisation. LMC implementations are usually not case sensitive, so this would make those two labels the same. Better use entirely different labels.
- `BRP PO`: The label `PO` points to the very next instruction, so this means that code execution will *always* continue at that instruction, whether you branch or not. It makes this instruction useless.
- `O       DAT 79`: this line appears right after a set of instructions that ends with `OTC`. If ever that code is executed, it will run into this `DAT` line. That could lead to undefined behaviour. You don't want this to happen. So make sure that `DAT` mailboxes are shielded from code execution. Add a `HLT` before a block of `DAT` to avoid that they are ever executed as if they were code. You have a similar issue at `P       DAT 80`.
- `BRZ EXIT`: at the `EXIT` address, you have a `BRP`, but as you can only arrive there when the accumulator is zero, the negative flag will not be set, and so `BRP` will branch *always*. Note that `BRP` branches when the negative flag is not set.
- `ODDE`: this label is never referenced, and that code block is never executed. You could consider changing the `BRA` -- that appears just before it -- to a `BRP`. Then the execution will fall through when the last subtraction led to a negative result (virtually -1 in your case, but the accumulator is undefined).

If you correct all these issues, you'll get to an implementation that will be very close to [this working version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64387413/5459839)

Comment: Could you give some feed-back? Did this answer your question?